# Преобразование шестнадцатеричной строки в шестнадцатеричную байтовую строку. Проблема с символами ASCII

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, byte, serial

Мне необходимо получить байтовую строку в шестнадцатеричном виде **b'\x15\x10...'** для ее дальнейшей отправки в serial порт.
Метод `bytes.fromhex` и `unhexlify` работают:

```
print(bytes.fromhex('151000149700'))
>>> b'\x15\x10\x00\x14\x97\x00'
```

Но не в случаях, когда появляются числа из кодировки ASCII:

```
print(bytes.fromhex('151000149729'))
>>> b'\x15\x10\x00\x14\x97)'
```

Как видно, вместо **29** я получаю **)**
Такой результат меня не устраивает. Как мне преобразовать **'151000149729'** к виду **b'\x15\x10\x00\x14\x97\x29\xf7\x2C'**?

Кусок кода, который я использую:

```
import crcmod.predefined
from binascii import unhexlify
str = '151000149729'
str2 = unhexlify(str)
crc16 = crcmod.predefined.Crc('modbus')
crc16.update(str2)
crc_16 = crc16.hexdigest()
crc16_1 = crc_16[:2]  #
crc16_2 = crc_16[2:]  # 
crc_16 = crc16_2 + crc16_1
crc_16 = str + crc_16
print(bytes.fromhex(crc_16))
```

Comment: Вам нужно отравить в serial 4 символа "\", "x", "2", "9" или один с кодом 29h?

Comment: Но ведь `\x29` это и есть `) `

Answer (score 3):

Как часто бывает, это вопрос **представления**, а не **хранения** данных:

```
for b in bytes.fromhex('151000149729'):
    print(hex(b))
```

Вывод:

```
0x15
0x10
0x0
0x14
0x97
0x29
```

Последний байт у вас именно `0x29`, просто при **печати** байтовой строки те символы, которые имеют какое-то осмысленное печатное изображение, печатаются в этом осмысленном изображении (в вашем случае это скобка), а вот те, которые не имеют символа отображения - те печатаются как `0xNN` именно поэтому.